# Spring cloud streams configuration for Azure eventhub with service principle

Tags: spring-boot, azure, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

Trying configure spring cloud stream to consume from Azure event hub. Switching authentication from SAS key to service principle using below yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      azure:
        client-id: XXXX
        client-secret: XXXXX
      bindings:
        input:
          binder: helixInput
          destination: destination
          group: ${CONSUMER_GROUP:}
      binders:
        rabbitOutput:
          type: rabbit
          environment:
            spring:
        helixInput:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: <Azure hostID >:9093
                      configuration:
                        sasl:
                          jaas:
                            config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="$ConnectionString" password="Endpoint=sb://<<hostID>>;client-id=<<client-id>>;client-secret="<<secretID>>";EntityPath=destination";
                          mechanism: ${KAFKA_INPUT_SASL_MECHANISM:PLAIN}
                        security:
                          protocol: ${KAFKA_INPUT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL:SASL_SSL}
```

But getting error Like

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value not specified for key 'service_principle_azure' in JAAS config
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasConfig.parseAppConfigurationEntry(JaasConfig.java:116) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasConfig.(JaasConfig.java:63) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.load(JaasContext.java:90) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.loadClientContext(JaasContext.java:84) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:124) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:67) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:99) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:382) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]

Answer (score 0):

Example is available at github location with one eventhub namespace : https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-dev-docs/blob/master/articles/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-java-app-kafka-azure-event-hub.md